# What does "%" in front of the variable in SAS pass-through exactly do / or means ?

Tags: sql, macros, sas, pass-through

what exactly does "%" in pass through means ? I got this code from others, the code works fine but I just don't understand why would have to put % in front of the variables. If it's a %macro I don't see any macro code in library. Any explanation would help

```
proc sql;
  connect to odbc as d(datasrc=source);
  create table out as select * from connection to d
  (
    select
      t.id,t.rule_id,
      %application_id,
      t.date,
      %dpv, %dpvfn1, %dpvfn2, %dpvfn3,
      %AddressValid,%AddressValidMsg,%AddressType,    
      from &db2 t
      join &db3 dxs on t.id=dxs.id
 left join &db4 dxr on t.id=dxr.id
  );
  disconnect from d;
quit;
```

Comment: What type of DBMS are you connecting to?

Comment: Also, if you want to double check if it's a macro call, maybe try something like `%put %application_id;` and see if that writes anything to the log

Comment: Finally, you can check if there are other macros being loaded through the autocall facility: `%put %sysfunc(getoption(sasautos));`

Comment: %put %track_id;
cast(  substr(cast(uncompress(id) as char(80000)),    (locate('<REFERENCEID>',cast(uncompress(id) as char(80000))) + 13),
locate('</REFERENCEID>',cast(uncompress(id) as char(80000))) - locate('<REFERENCEID>'      ,cast(uncompress(id) as char(80000))) - 13   ) as
char(12) ) as track_id   ..... So it's a macro right ?

Comment: Above is the output I got. So it is a macro ? Where can I find the original code ? I don't work a lot with macro I know how to create and use macro by %macroname(var=blah);   . but this is different. Any explanation would help , thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%MACRO X;
VAR
%MEND;

The above example is a definition of a macro.

In your question, all the columns with % are actually doing macro calls and replacing the calls with the values present in their macro definitions.For eg in ur select query...

```
select
      t.id,t.rule_id,
      %application_id,
      t.date,
      %dpv, %dpvfn1, %dpvfn2, %dpvfn3,
      %AddressValid,%AddressValidMsg,%AddressType,    
      from &db2 t
      join &db3 dxs on t.id=dxs.id
 left join &db4 dxr on t.id=dxr.id

%application_id,%dpv, %dpvfn1, %dpvfn2, %dpvfn3,%AddressValid,%AddressValidMsg,%AddressType
```

All these above macro calls will retrieve their corresponding definitions and replace them in the place of your select columns...

Comment: Thanks  , I am thinking there should be a better the way of doing this right ?